# Electron Levels of Atomic Nitrogen Vs. Molecular Nitrogen

Tags: energy, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

So I have a question about the the affect of the electron energy levels of Nitrogen when it becomes diatomic. In Figure 1 below you see the electron energy levels of atomic Nitrogen, and it shows that it takes 14.53 eV to ionize a Nitrogen atom. Figure 2 shows the Molecular Orbital energy for Nitrogen. It's not on Figure 2, but the ionization energy of N2 is 15.57 eV or thereabouts. I think that's from the 2p sigma level. So my question is, are any of the higher level orbitals in figure 1 also adjusted down? Or is it just the 2p ground state that is moved down making for a larger gap to the 3s level while leaving the energy level differences between the other orbitals  the same as the atomic energy levels? IF it's the former, does anyone have the actual numbers of the of all those orbital levels?

[image]

Figure 1 Atomic Nitrogen Energy Levels

[image]

Figure 2